# Content Editor - Dynamic Content by Workspace Instance?

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

How can I make the content editor display different content for each workspace instance?

For example, I'd like to display the corresponding agenda for each meeting date listed.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer to your question but may serve as a workaround for the same.

You can use the date filter and 'XYZ' list web part. On setting up the connection between the two, your list web part will show the items based on the date selected from the calendar shown for date filter.